# AssemblyInfo patcher in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, teamcity

`TeamCity` has a nice feature called `AssemblyInfo patcher`. I used it to set AssembliInfo version equal to build number (only in binaries). Now I need to implement the same behaviour in `TFS`. Is there any tool for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a guide for doing similar with the [TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20AssemblyInfo%20build%20activity)  and another to [Create a Custom WF Activity to Sync Version and Build Numbers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the update of version numbers specifically for AssemblyInfo files, then I would suggest taking a look at the [TfsVersion activity in the Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20TfsVersion%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation) on CodePlex.  You can also take a look at the [AssemblyInfo build workflow activity](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20AssemblyInfo%20build%20activity) available on there as well.